# Filtering user Ids from an array of users

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I wish to find all users, not the current User. A pair of users are stored within a "Room" array under this collection structure:

**structure of each room (from another html page)**

```
var newRoom = Rooms.insert({
   owner    : Meteor.userId(),
   receiver : receiver,
   people   : [ owner , receiver ],
});
```

**Collection.js (using dburles collection helper)**

```
Rooms.helpers({
  receiverName: function() {  
    return Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: this.receiver }).username; 
  }
});
```

**html**

```
<!-- **allRooms.html** Works fine, names appear --> 
  {{#each rooms}} {{receiverName}}{{/each }}

<!-- **roomDetail.html**  names dont show, this.receiver undefined --> 
    {{receiverName}}
```

**roomDetail js template helper**

```
self.subscribe('room', Router.current().params._id);
self.subscribe('users');
});
```

How do I return and display the user's Id thats not the current user from the `people` field which is an array? I hope to show it in the child page (roomDetail).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- `Rooms` is a collection, and you already have a `room` document to search on.
- You only want to fetch a single user.

Give this a try:

```
// The list of userIds in room minus the current user's id.
var userIds = _.without(room.People, Meteor.userId());

// Assuming we want only one user...
var user = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: userIds[0] });
```

Some thoughts about your original code:

- You can't include references to `Rooms` in your `Meteor.users` selector unless `Rooms` is a field of users. Mongo has no notion of joins.
- `$ne` isn't that you want. If you had 100 users published, and your array only contained 2 users (one of which you didn't want), using `$ne` would return 99 users.

---

Based on your comments, it looks like you need this in a [collection helper](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers). Maybe something like this:

```
Rooms.helpers({
  findUser: function() {
    var userIds = _.without(this.People, Meteor.userId());
    return Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: userIds[0] });
  },
});
```

And then elsewhere in your code, for a given `room` instance you could do:

```
room.findUser()
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that. Maybe you'd return `user` from a helper somewhere on the client?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example collection helper. Maybe that will help guide you in the right direction.

Comment: I updated the answer to be compatible with ES5. Yes, this helper assumes a room as its context so maybe `{{#with room}} {{#with findUser }} ... {{/with}} {{/with}}` or something. Again, it's really hard for me to say exactly what to write w/o seeing the source.

Comment: Thanks @David Weldon, Im unable to solve it. I shortened the code to isolate the problem but didnt help. I have added a more data to the above.  Tough nut to crack but likely I missed out something simple. Tried tweaking both pub and sub and no differences.